# Not able to install an application to Android tablet

Tags: android

I build an Android app for Android 4.1(ICS). However I am not able to install it to a tablet. It shows an error as `The application cannot be installed`. Can any one help me to sort out this problem?

Comment: Please check Android version of Tab from Settings of device and compare with your manifest <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="?" />

Comment: Confirm whether your Tablet also contains 4.1 or not? My Friend `4.1 isn't ICS`, It's `JB`.

Answer (score 0):

First check what is your device OS version.if it is lower then 4.1 ,app will not run on this.

try to change `project.property` file in your project.

may be you have `target=15 or 14` reduce it according to your tablet i.e `target = 11 or 13`